# Show "Select a ..."on dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dropdown menu created with the code below which fetches all brands from a brands table. It uses a while loop  thus showing all on the menu starting alphabetically (i.e.,  Adiddas and so on). Therefore I don't list them as individual `<options>` line by line.

```
echo "<form action=\"type.INC.php\" method=\"get\">\n";
echo "<select name=\"brand\">\n";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($hook);
if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($hook,"SELECT brandid, brandname FROM brands WHERE brandid "));
{
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i", $brandid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $brandid, $brandname);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
    {
    $brandname = htmlspecialchars($brandname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    echo "<option value=\"$brandid\">$brandname </option>"; 
    }    
echo "</select>\n";
echo "<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" id=\"brandid\" value=\"submit\" />\n";
echo "</form> \n";
```

How can I  show the sentence "SELECT A BRAND" to appear as the default first value? Should I just enter  "SELECT A BRAND"  into my brands table and assign a primaryID of zero to it?

Any better way to do this?

All of my searches regarding this question result in topics relating to the 'select=selected attribute'.

Thanks,
Jen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it manually before the loop:

```
echo "<form action=\"type.INC.php\" method=\"get\">\n";
echo "<select name=\"brand\">\n";
// Select a brand, empty value:
echo "<option value=\"\">(SELECT A BRAND)</option>";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($hook);
if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($hook,"SELECT brandid, brandname FROM brands WHERE brandid "));
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i", $brandid);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $brandid, $brandname);
    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
    {
        $brandname = htmlspecialchars($brandname, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        echo "<option value=\"$brandid\">$brandname </option>"; 
    }    
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo "<input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" id=\"brandid\" value=\"submit\" />\n";
    echo "</form> \n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

`echo "<option>SELECT A BRAND</option>";`

as the third line of your code.